# What is the answer for the $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, limits

Let $t\in (0,\pi)$ and $n$ change in natural numbers. I am wondering what is the answer to the following limit.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}.$$

Thank you.

Comment: Raymond and I interpreted the question differently in our answers. Since you started out with "Let $t\in(0,\pi)$", I thought that $t$ is fixed; but the question makes a lot more sense if it's intended to be about convergence of distributions as Raymond interpreted it. If so, I think you should clarify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well $\ \frac {\sin(nt)}{\pi t}\to \delta(t)\ $ as $n\to\infty\ $ ([equation (9)](http://www.physics.usu.edu/riffe/3750/Lecture%2015.pdf)) so that (since $\frac t{\sin(t)}\to1$ as $t\to0$) : 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}=\pi \frac t{\sin(t)}\delta(t)=\pi\delta(t)$$

Comment: Your answer should be $\pi \frac t{\sin(t)}\delta(t)$, since you are not asked to take the limit as t goes to zero.

Comment: By the way, $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @Mhenni: $f(t)\delta(t)=f(0)\delta(t)$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @joriki: Note that for this property to hold we require that $f(x)$ to be continuous at $0$. But our function is with removable discontinuity at $0$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: this has to be considered from the point of view of distributions. From a distribution point of view the value at a point ($0$ here) is unimportant since we are considering families of equivalent functions. The 'extended' continue function with value $0$ is from this point of view 'equal' to $\frac {\sin(t)}t$. You may too replace $f(0)$ by the limit as $t\to 0$ of $f(t)$ if you prefer.

Comment: (this was 'with value $1$ at $0$' of course)

Comment: I just want to make things clear.

Answer (score 10):

$\sin t$ doesn't depend on $n$, so you can pull it out; so basically you're asking for the limit of $\sin(nt)$ for $n\to\infty$. Since $\sin x$ oscillates, there's no such thing.